# VideoView info/warning and 'unhandled events' even after videoView.stopPlayback()

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, media-player, android-videoview

I call videoView.stopPlayback() which internally calls:

```
 mediaPlayer.stop()
 mediaPlayer.release()
 mediaPlayer = null
```

Yet I get the warning in logcat mediaplayer went away with unhandled events.

Note that upon playing the video I get MediaPlayerNative: info/warning (3, 0), even though videoView is pretty straight forward for local mp4's:

```
videoView.setVideoPath()
videoView.setOnPreparedListener{ -> videoView.start()}
```

Comment: "I get the warning in logcat mediaplayer went away with unhandled events" -- on the whole, `MediaPlayer` and related classes are very noisy in Logcat. In addition, these sorts of lower-level messages may vary by device, as manufacturers can tinker with the Android implementation. If you feel that `VideoView` has a bug, and you get the same sorts of messages across multiple devices, create a sample project that reproduces the problem and file a bug report. Beyond that... I guess that I do not know what you are asking here. Sorry if I am misinterpreting your question!

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this you need to add `reset()` before `release()`

```
if(mediaPlayer!=null) {
        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer=null;
    }
```

Comment: I'm using videoView. I did give your answer a try since this would be correct for an audio mediaPlayer. I assigned a global variable for mediaPlayer when I get a return from videoView.  and implement your code. I get  E/SurfaceView: Exception configuring surface java.lang.IllegalStateException at android.media.MediaPlayer._reset(Native Method).